# Estimating the randomness of a LCG

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, self-study, distributions, statistical-significance

Suppose that I want to test the randomness and uniformness of the linear congruential generator. Suppose that I have the null hypothesis that the sequence generated by the LCG is idd uniform on $[0,1]$. I choose a seed and let the LCG generate a sequence of $n$ numbers and I apply the monkey test, the permutation test, and the runs test to check for i.i.d.-ness and uniformity. Let say I get the following $p$-value for each test:

- Monkey test: $p$-value $=0.16$
- Permutation test: $p$-value $=0.36$
- Runs test: $p$-value $= 0.45$

I'm wondering how I can use these values to say something about the reliability of the LCG. The different $p$-values do not give me enough proof to say that the LCG is not uniform and idd. However, I think I might be able to use the fact that under the null-hypothesis the $p$-values should have a $U(0,1)$ distribution. Would it be useful to repeat the tests for $n$ different LCG sequences, and check whether the expected value of the $p$-values is equal to $1/2$?

**Question:** How can I use these $p$-values (or other metrics) to tell me something about randomness of an LCG?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this question is predicated on some basic misunderstandings and would suggest clearing them up before getting into any details. "Not random" cannot serve as a null hypothesis for quantitative testing, because it does not lead to any specific information about the LCG. All the tests you quote adopt null hypotheses that express particular aspects of "randomness," such as having a uniform distribution or independence of the values. As such, the p-values are interpreted as they would be for any null hypothesis test.

Comment: Thank your for your reply! I think I understand your point; would you agree to with my edited null hypothesis? And if so; what could you say about the iid-ness or uniform-ness of the LCG based on the $p$-values?

Comment: They do not reject the null hypotheses.  They are, however, impossible to interpret because their meaning depends (heavily) on the length of the sequence you tested.  Good tests tend to look at sequences of $10^8$ or more bits, which enables them to find relatively small deviations.

Comment: Furthermore (to @whuber's points), these $p$-values are all based on the same sequence, hence not independent.

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks for your reply! Would you suggest using different sequences for the different tests?

Comment: It would be a waste of time to use a separate sequence for each separate statistical test, because the objective is not to make different tests, but simply to look for (and characterize) any tiny deviations from uniform randomness.